JPA Query with NOT LIKE doesn't work to filter ips
I am working with a JPQL query to filter some gateways ips ending with 1 (the column in the database is of type INET but on the entity is of type String):
...AND concat(c.ip,'') not LIKE '%.1'
THe query generated for this inside the application looks like this:
AND NOT (c_ip || ? LIKE ?))

I know using a native sql would work either with bitwise operations or with LIKE but I can't use native since I need a list and it won't allow it, tried it multiple ways.
I also tried to send through a parameter the value like this:
concat(c.ip,'') not LIKE :excludedValue
binding the value like this: query.setParameter("excludedValue","%.1");
And it doesn't work. The strange thing is that it works directly in my SQL IDE, with concat and like on the same data.
A bit of help would be much appreciated, thank you!

What value are you binding to :excludedValue ?

The value I am binding is this: query.setParameter("excludedValue","%.1"); I added it now to the question also

Then the generated SQL/JPQL should not be AND NOT (c_ip || ? LIKE ?)) ... I am not sure this is reproducible.

Also tried with NOT LIKE  CONCAT('%',:excludedValue)") 
query.setParameter("excludedValue",".1");

EJBQueryImpl(ReportQuery(referenceClass=... sql=".. AND NOT (c_ip || ? LIKE ?))"))  this is the query generated for passing the value directly as NOT LIKE '%.1'

Since the ip column is of some exotic type which JPQL doesn't know about, you will have to use native SQL here I'm afraid.

yes that's what I'm afraid of because native SQL won't let me pass a list and I also need a list in my query. I will further look for how I can check that ip ends with  for inet column

It is still possible to bind a collection to a Java prepared statement, with some effort.  Post the full query and maybe someone can answer.

which "database" is it exactly? hover over the tags "sql" and "database" both are very vague and not useful here - tag with the database you actually use

consider using a left join" to knock out the rows ending ".1" in that column e.g. ... left join (select inet_column from inet_source_table where inet_column like '%.1)  i ON c.ip = i.inet_column where i.inet_column is null or perhaps use |NOT| EXISTS
